# Getting many errors while executing the command npx create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I am getting many errors while executing the command npx create-react-app my-app in Git bash terminal. I am using node version 16.15.1.
Please help. How to fix this problem

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_301      
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Lenovo\OneDrive\Desktop\R
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_301 ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-26T11_33_05_384Z-debug-
```

0.log